# Joining two variables based on unique ID using AWK/SED

Tags: unix, sed, awk, ksh

I have two variables which are comma separated lists.  I would like to join these two variables by appending the lines based on their unique id.

Example below:

```
var1="
id1,data1,data2,data3
id2,data1,data2,data3
id3,data1,data2,data3
id4,data1,data2,data3
"

var 2="
id1,data4,data5,data6
id2,data4,data5,data6
id3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data4,data5,data6
"

output="
id1,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id2,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id3,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
"
```

I'm not the best at AWK and while I can decrypt it I still have troubles coming up with commands.  If you could help that would be great!

Comment: Any particular reason you need sed or awk?

Comment: Not really, just assumed that would be the tool to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not set on `sed` or `awk`, you can use `join`:

```
$ cat in1
id1,data1,data2,data3
id2,data1,data2,data3
id3,data1,data2,data3
id4,data1,data2,data3
x
$ cat in2
id1,data4,data5,data6
id2,data4,data5,data6
id3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data4,data5,data6
y
$ join -t, -j1 in1 in2
id1,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id2,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id3,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
$ join -t, -a1 -a2 -j1 in1 in2
id1,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id2,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id3,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
x
y
```

Use the `-a1 -a2` options if you want to see unmatched lines, otherwise don't.

Note that the files need to be sorted, if they're not already, you can use the `sort` command for that.

```
sort in1 > in1.sorted
sort in2 > in2.sorted
```

Comment: or this `join -t, <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Comment: Definitely seems like the easiest way to go about this.  Even though I asked for SED or AWK, the join seems much simpler.  And I like simple code :)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
output=$(echo "$var1" | 
sed 's|^\([^,]*,\)\(.*\)|/^\1/s/^[^,]*,\\(.*\\)/\1\2,\\1/|;$a\/^$/d' | 
sed -f - <(echo "$var2"))
echo "$output"
id1,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id2,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id3,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
```

Comment: my eyes … my eyes … :) +1 (just bcoz it's you and sed)

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Set the Field Separator to "," and Output FS to ","
BEGIN{
        FS=","; OFS="," 
        }

# Store each line of file1 to an array a, indexed at $1        
NR==FNR{
            a[$1]=$0;next 
            } 

# Check if the column 1 of file2 is present in that array. Print if it is.        
($1 in a){  
            print a[$1],$2,$3,$4
            }
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f1
id1,data1,data2,data3
id2,data1,data2,data3
id3,data1,data2,data3
id4,data1,data2,data3
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f2
id1,data4,data5,data6
id2,data4,data5,data6
id3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data4,data5,data6
[jaypal:~/Temp] ./s.awk f1 f2
id1,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id2,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id3,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
```

#### Using `join` as stated by **`@kevin`**. Here is a simplified version.

```
join -t, <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] join -t, <(sort f1) <(sort f2)
id1,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id2,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id3,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
id4,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6
```